# Making row ranges adjust

Tags: excel, rows, spreadsheet

In my Excel spreadsheet, I've got a cell that is `=SUM(C6:C19)`. If I go to `C20` and add a row, that formula will not adjust. I want it to change to `=SUM(C6:C20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest way** is to leave a one cell space between the bottom of your values and the sum formula.

**For example**, Cell A20 currently sums cells A1 to A19. in you insert a row below A19, the sum won't won't include the new row right?

Well, if you **put the sum formula in cell A21** and **sum from A1 to A20** (even though a20 hasn't got anything in it), **when you insert a row above cell A20 your sum formula will include it.**

The offset thing mentioned as an alternative answer is a great way to do it also, but is more confusing, this is what I do if I want to keep it **simple**.

Comment: I should've said this: C5 =SUM(C6:C19).

Comment: this could still work, if C20 is blank make the sum c6:c20 then whenever you do an insert on c20 it will be included.

Comment: The ideal way would be to have calculations on a different sheet, then you could just do a sum on the entire column

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a static range in the formula you can use a dynamic range:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, height, [width]))
```

For example:

```
=SUM(OFFSET('My Sheet'!$C$6, 0, 0, COUNTA('My Sheet'!$C:$C)))
```

This assumes nothing else is in column C. You can restrict the height range if necessary*:

```
=SUM(OFFSET('My Sheet'!$C$6, 0, 0, COUNTA('My Sheet'!$C$6:$C$30)))
```

*From Lunatik's comment

Comment: Bear in mind that this assumes nothing else is in column C though. You can restrict the height range if necessary, e.g. =SUM(OFFSET('My Sheet'!$C$6, 0, 0, COUNTA('My Sheet'!$C$6:$C$30)))